# how to export datagrid to excel(.xlsx format only) without using server side technology and as3xls?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

Presently I am using as3xls.swc to export datagrid to excel which is giving me only to save as .xls format which is opening in microsoft excel 2010 which is OK for me, but it is only opening in protected mode where I am unable to do any edits or save it. So, can anybody know any other way to save as .xlsx format in the client side itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [export to excel using as3xls protected view flex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341134/export-to-excel-using-as3xls-protected-view-flex)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please do not ask the same question twice.  If you have additional information you can edit your previous question.

Comment: yeah, but I'm trying this from last 2 days but know use, so I need somebody's help badly

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to export your datagrid in CSV format? Typically the .csv extension is also associated with Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Protected mode is a feature of Excel within the Microsoft operating system. They're trying to keep you from inadvertently downloading viruses. You can defeat these measures by modifying the Excel trust store. It has nothing to do with your code, and you don't need to use older versions of Excel.

I find it easiest to add a trusted location (like your desktop).

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/what-is-protected-view-HA010355931.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can export to Excel2007 - its just an xml file format. WE have some details on our blog: http://blog.flexicious.com/post/Flexicious-30-Release-Grid-Edition.aspx. Keep in mind however, it generates an XML file, which when you double click on, will correctly open up excel (Assuming you have excel 2007 or the reader installed).